# Remove saved checkmarks in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was working on my project that a table can retain the checkmarks in tableview cell when I scroll. And I did it, but my problem now is, how can I remove those saved checkmarks now? Thank you.

Here's the code that I used in order to save checkmarks:

```
-(NSString *)getKeyForIndex:(int)index {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY%d",index];
}

-(BOOL)getCheckedForIndex:(int)index{
  if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]] boolValue]==YES){
    return YES;
  }else{
    return NO;
  }
}

-(void)checkedCellAtIndex:(int)index{
  BOOL boolChecked = [self getCheckedForIndex:index];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!boolChecked] forKey:[self getKeyForIndex:index]];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: You can use `removeObjectForKey` but using NSUserDefaults like this is a bit icky (technical term)

Answer (score 0):

To remove a key use `removeObjectForKey:`, to set a boolean value for a key use `setBool:forKey:`, to get a boolean value for a key use `boolForKey`. Also these can be found in the [`NSUserDefaults` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

Also whatever you do never write `if(e == YES)` just write `if(e)` (the former may give you an incorrect result - why is left as an exercise); and rather than writing `if(e) then return YES; else return NO;`, where `e` is a `BOOL` valued expression, it is usually better to write `return e`.

HTH